# How can I smb share a Windows folder so it is accessible to Linux machines?

Tags: windows-7, linux, samba, smb

I want to create an SMB share on my Windows machine, so that my Linux machine can see and access it over the network. I tried setting up 'sharing' on the folder, but this hasn't worked.

**How can I set up the folder to work correctly with SMB on Windows 7?**

Comment: What distro are you running? In *buntus, the file managers tend to come with "connect to network" option where the shares on Windows machine show up automatically.

Comment: What you are saying is not clear. What did you try and what failed? In line of principle, if you `share` a directory and give access permissions to everyone, your Linux pc will have no problem whatsoever to connect, it needs no special configuration. So what exactly failed?

Answer (score 0):

Install smbfs:

```
sudo apt-get install smbfs
```

Create folder  /media/linkshare:

```
sudo mkdir /media/linkshare
```

Mount folder:

```
sudo mount -t cifs "//<ip address>/public documents" /media/linkshare -o guest,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

Mount folder requires authentication using login and password:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<ip address>/WindowsShare /media/linkshare -o username=windowsuser,password=windowspass,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```